# Regular expression to check a number with dash and + symbol

Tags: regex

1. numberic value with minmum 10 digit maximumn 15 digit  (eg. 9123456789)
2. 1st character can be +               (eg. +919123456789)
3. Dash symbol "-" can be anywhere but not in first, last and repeated (eg. +91-02-3-456-78-90-21)

Please help me. I have no effective idea in field of regular expression

Comment: What have you tried? Did you check out [a tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)?

Comment: Sir, I have tried but i have no idea to stop repeating of dash symbol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one possible solution:

```
^\+?(?:\d-?){9,14}\d$
```

Explanation:

```
^          # anchor the pattern to the beginning of the string
\+?        # optional literal +
(?:\d-?)   # a digit, followed by an optional hyphen
{9,14}     # 9 to 14 of those
\d         # another digit (to make that 10 to 15, and disallow hyphens at the end)
$          # anchor the pattern to the end of the string
```